# Is truffle based on node and is it possible to run some kind of node debugger in order to pause the Javascript tests and examine variables?

Tags: truffle, javascript, nodejs, testing

I am currently developing a Dapp and using truffle test to verify the contract. However, I find that I am also debugging the Javascript that runs the test with a lot of console.log() statements. This is time consuming and inefficient. I would like to use a debugger to examine the Javascript in order to refine my tests, and also because I'm still figuring out how to interact with web3 correctly.

Comment: This may be out of scope for the original question, but any pointers to help debuggin truffle tests in IntelliJ would be awesome :-)

Comment: @TripleSpeeder Have a look - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/debugging-js-unit-tests-with-truffle-framework-in-vs-code/43633#43633 - links to VS Code and node inspsector in Chrome dev tools...

Answer (score 2):

Truffle is built on NodeJS so you can use any of node's debugging tools. Here's how you can use node's built in debugger:

```
$ node --inspect-brk $(which truffle) <truffle args>
```

or if you installed truffle locally:

```
$ node --inspect-brk $(npm bin)/truffle <truffle args>
```

This will execute `truffle <truffle args>` and break right away. Follow the directions to attach. If you don't want to break right away, replace `--inspect-brk` with `--inspect` and use `debugger` statements.

Comment: Did you mean "replace --inspect-brk with --inspect"?

Comment: @RobertOschler Yes