# Debugging JS unit tests with truffle framework in VS code

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, dapp-debugging

Is there a way to debug JS unit tests for smart contracts? I use VS Code for development, and when I try to run a Mocha debugger it complains that `artifacts` is not defined. I briefly looked at truffle code, it looks like it adds `artifacts`, `contract` and some other global js variables when it runs the unit tests. Is there a way for me to add those explicitly in the JS unit test file so I could debug that unit test file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your lucky day (had to solve this few days ago):

See that you have `truffle-core` locally in your project. If not, do:

`npm install truffle-core`

Then use a configuration similar to this: ( Debug -> Open Configurations )

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "truffle test (debugable)",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules/truffle-core/cli.js",
            "args": [
                "test"
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

Or add a new one (simple "node"  launch, then edit it)

If your code does not spawn another node process (brings trouble which are essentially an node.js bug), you should be good.

Comment: Since `truffle-core` has been deprecated. Install `truffle` instead. Also the program path would now look like this: `${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js`

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution above can also be used to start the debugger from command line and debug in node inspector (in Chrome dev tools):

```
npm install truffle-core
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/truffle-core/cli.js test test/test_to_debug.js
```

---

**UPDATE:** `truffle-core` https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-core

> ⚠️ This repo is deprecated ⚠️
>   Truffle has moved all modules to a monorepo at trufflesuite/truffle. See you over there!

`node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js test test/test_to_debug.js`

---

Now open the debugger:

- Open chrome://inspect page and click the "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" link
- The cli.js file should be opened with the execution paused on the first line
- Add the test sources into the inspector: click the "Filesystem" on the left and then "Add folder to workspace".
- Browse to the folder with tests and add it.
- Open the file with the test to debug and set the breakpoint, continue the execution until it reaches the breakpoint
- Now you can step through your test, inspect variables, etc

Related links:

[Truffle - Debugging unit tests](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/822)

[Truffle - Launching "truffle test" from JS code (debugging)](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/810)

[How can I debug a truffle JS unit test with vscode?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39958/how-can-i-debug-a-truffle-js-unit-test-with-vscode)

[how can I run a truffle test in a debugger?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14031/how-can-i-run-a-truffle-test-in-a-debugger)

[Debugging Node.js Apps](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/)

Comment: **HINT**: I'm using `CMD + P` to jump to file. At first not all files are loaded, using `debugger` statement in the code...